# Why is my call to a method or property ambiguous? (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can't work out why my code is saying that a method or or property is Ambiguous. If somebody can tell me why and explain that would be great. It's these two methods i'm having issues with:

```
        PostCodeInfo MatchingPostCode = Find(PostCodeList, PostCode);


        PostCodeInfo MatchingPostCode2 = Find(PostCodeList, PostCode2);
```

Full Code for Context:

```
    namespace GetPost
{
    public class PostCodeInfo
    {
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string Locality { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string PostCode2 { get; set; }




        public PostCodeInfo(string postCode, string postcode2, string locality, string state)
        {
            PostCode = postCode;
            PostCode2 = postcode2; 
            Locality = locality;
            State = state;


        }
    }



    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected static List<PostCodeInfo> PostCodeList;

        protected bool Contains(List<PostCodeInfo> listToCheck, string postCode)
        { //This is a very slow search that you normally wouldn't use, but to keep things simple we'll just iterate through every list item and check for our post code
            foreach (PostCodeInfo entry in listToCheck)
                if (entry.PostCode == postCode)
                    return true;
            return false;
        }




        protected void Load_Postcodes(string CSVFileName)
        {
            PostCodeList = new List<PostCodeInfo>();

            StreamReader Reader = null;
            try
            {
                Reader = new StreamReader(CSVFileName);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                lblOutput.Text = string.Format("Error: Check your file path and file name for the post code CSV are correct! Current setting is: '{0}'", CSVFileName);
                return;
            }
            Reader.ReadLine(); //Get rid of the first line of the file which contains the names of the columns (e.g. "Pcode", "Locality" , etc.)
            while (Reader.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                string CurrentLine = Reader.ReadLine();
                string[] Columns = CurrentLine.Split(new char[] {','});
                for (int i = 0; i < Columns.Length; i++)
                { //Remove the redundant double quotes included in the CSV file
                    Columns[i] = Columns[i].TrimStart(new char[] { '"' });
                    Columns[i] = Columns[i].TrimEnd(new char[] { '"' });
                }
                PostCodeInfo NewPostCode = new PostCodeInfo(Columns[0], Columns[1], Columns[2], Columns[3]); //Consider error checking each column in your assignments
                if (Contains(PostCodeList, NewPostCode.PostCode) == false)
                { //Don't add the PostCodeInfo if we already encountered this post code
                    PostCodeList.Add(NewPostCode);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (PostCodeList == null) //This if statement isn't necessary, but if we don't have it we have to re-read our CSV file every time someone refreshs our web form! That's extremely slow.
            {
                Load_Postcodes(@"F:\PostCode-Full_20130228.csv"); //Put in your CSV file location here! Warning: Relative file paths go from the server executable file path, NOT your web app's "bin" file path. Use a full file path if you have problems
                //                                                       The '@' denotes a string literal ('\' characters are treated as normal characters, i.e. as literal characters)
            }

        }

        protected PostCodeInfo Find(List<PostCodeInfo> listToCheck, string postCode)
        { //Again, the search here is not what you would normally use because of how slow it is but we use it to keep things simple
          //Those of you who want a better solution can look into the SortedDictionary to use instead of a List (MSDN is very useful!)
            foreach (PostCodeInfo entry in listToCheck)
            {
                if (entry.PostCode == postCode)
                    return entry;
            }
            return null; //Return nothing if it's not in our list
        }


        protected PostCodeInfo Find(List<PostCodeInfo> listToCheck, string postCode2)
        { //Again, the search here is not what you would normally use because of how slow it is but we use it to keep things simple
            //Those of you who want a better solution can look into the SortedDictionary to use instead of a List (MSDN is very useful!)
            foreach (PostCodeInfo entry in listToCheck)
            {
                if (entry.PostCode == postCode2)
                    return entry;
            }
            return null; //Return nothing if it's not in our list
        }





        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string PostCode = txtOriginPost.Text;
            string PostCode2 = txtDestPost.Text;
            //See if you're able to put some error checking in for the post code after you've finished the second half of prac 2!

            PostCodeInfo MatchingPostCode = Find(PostCodeList, PostCode);
            if (MatchingPostCode == null)
            {
                lblOutput.Text = "Your postcode could not be found!";
            }
            else
            {
                lblOutput.Text = string.Format("Your post code is in {0}, {1}", MatchingPostCode.Locality, MatchingPostCode.State);
            }

            PostCodeInfo MatchingPostCode2 = Find(PostCodeList, PostCode2);

            if (MatchingPostCode2 == null)
            {
                lblOutput2.Text = "Your postcode could not be found!";
            }
            else
            {
                lblOutput2.Text = string.Format("Your post code is in {0}, {1}", MatchingPostCode2.Locality, MatchingPostCode2.State);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you have defined two methods with the same signature.

Comment: Does your form even compile? The signatures for `Form1.Find(List<string>, string)` are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two calls are identical that's why:

```
protected PostCodeInfo Find(List<PostCodeInfo> listToCheck, string postCode)
protected PostCodeInfo Find(List<PostCodeInfo> listToCheck, string postCode2)
```

The param names are irrelevant. If you want to keep both methods simplest solution would just be to rename, have like `Find` and `Find2` or something (name them better really).

However, from the looks of your code they do identical things anyhow, so you should just be able to drop one. You could also completely do away with these methods and use LINQ extensions instead:

```
PostCodeInfo info = listToCheck.FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.PostCode == postCode);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 methods with the exact same signature:

```
protected PostCodeInfo Find(List<PostCodeInfo> x, string y);
```

The fact that they have different parameter names such as `postCode` and `postCode2` doesn't matter, it's only the type that's being considered.

Answer (score 1):

The signatures for both `Form1.Find(List<string>, string)` methods are the same. The form won't compile.

The code calling the method shows an error out of courtesy. Fix the `Find()` method first.

Answer (score 0):

In C# and most other languages a method signature is only defined by the methods name and the types of its input parameters.

You have two exactly identical definitions

```
 protected PostCodeInfo Find(List<PostCodeInfo> listToCheck, string postCode)
 protected PostCodeInfo Find(List<PostCodeInfo> listToCheck, string postCode2)
```

since there is no variation in the input parameters, nor the name.

You could should do

```
 protected PostCodeInfo Find(List<PostCodeInfo> listToCheck, string postCode)
 protected PostCodeInfo Find2(List<PostCodeInfo> listToCheck, string postCode)
```

and make the variation on the method name (note the identical names on the input).

But since your implementations are identical, you should probably just do with one method and be sure to send `postCode` respectively `postCode2` when you *invoke* the method.